# Partition SD card for use on a dual boot tablet

Tags: sd-card, partitions, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Windows 10/Android tablet device that has only 1 micro SDcard slot. I also have a 128GB microSD card that **I would like to split into a 96GB partition 1 for windows and 32GB partition 2 for android**. I have tried doing it using various of means through windows disk part or minitool partition but once I have successfully partitioned the sd card, when I mount it to the android OS, it automatically reformats the sd and mounts it as a 1-partition 128GB sd card... I'd like to know if what I want is possible and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: In my case, I partitioned my SD Card using a custom recovery

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think I'd want to mess with the warranty yet though since as far as I know, installing a custom recovery voids that...

Comment: Should work using a Linux maching (or LiveCD) with GParted. You could also try one of the available [partitioning apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_915) on Android (disclaimer: link goes to my Android site).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Izzy! I did try using Android partitioning apps however it seems that they "are not optimized" for my device. As for Linux, I would have to look deep into it as I am a total noob with that O/S... I was able to split the SD into 2 partitions though (using diskpart), a 32GB and 96GB partition. Android seems to read the 32gb partition fine at fat32 format... but I format the 96GB partition as NTFS for the windows o/s and it is recognized by windows at first - until I restart the tablet and the partition goes RAW immediately on the next bootup... I'm at a loss on what to do.

Comment: I don't know how windows 10 on a tablet deals with fat32 formatted partitions, but I know that with some Android devices, you can use a very large partition (tested with 64GB) formatted as fat32.

I **believe** that windows won't refuse to work with that (even though it probably won't let you create one such partition). Did you try this already?

Or don't you want Android to see the Windows partition? If that's the case, it isn't clear from your question.